# Is there a better way to restrict method calling than by passing a string "password"? C#

Tags: c#

For example: Let's say I only want a specific function (A) to be called from 2 specific places (B and C). Even though its possible to call A from other places (the function is public), I want to make sure I (or someone else) call the method via function B or C and not directly by mistake.

I've been thinking about it a lot and the only viable way I can come up with is something like:

```
public void A(string callingFrom, object arg1, object arg2)
{
    if (callingFrom != "B" && callingFrom != "C")
        throw new Exception("Call the function via B och C");


    // Some code
}
```

*And please don't write anything like "If you need to do that then you have done something wrong in the first place". Not every codebase is 100% optimal - to say the least...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Make function A `private` or `protected`.

Comment: Can you explain the use case which is leading you to have this kind of restrictions?

Comment: Yes, not every code base is optimal. But this almost certainly is the result of something else in your program being wrong, if you like it or not. The question is probably not "how do i prevent this from being called from something else" and try to attach a "password" to it. You should rather ask yourself why it is a problem to call this from other functions in the first place and fix that. For example for restricting visiblity there are acess modifieres.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use interfaces to control access. I.e. the method A is public, but is not exposed in the interface. B and C gets a reference to the actual class, while everyone else gets the interface. This protection can be side stepped by casting the object, but it can make casual miss-use more difficult.

Another option is to put A, B, and C in the same project, and make A [internal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal).

A third option would be to Use a method name that makes it clear that the method should only be used in some very special circumstances. If a developer sees method named a `DoNotCallThisMethodFromAnythingExceptBorC` with a prominent comment telling him why, he would probably not use it before investigating some more.

There is also [CallerMemberName](http://CallerMemberNameAttribute) that can be used to automatically inject calling method/file name.

There is also the [StackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=netcore-3.1) class that can be used to inspect the calling method.

But please do not use callerMemberName or StackTrace for more than logging. It can easily result in runtime errors that can be difficult to find, and since it is not something most people do, your colleagues (current and future) will probably rightfully complain.